# data is not passed in angular1 services i am using $routeparams

Tags: angularjs

I am following angular `ui-router` with dependency `angular-ui-router/1.0.3/`

angular dependency 1.2.x

```
angular.module('todoservice', [])
.factory('user', ['$http','$stateParams', function($http, $stateParams){          
     userDetails: function(id){                           
    //:id is working when I pass static Id which is present in mongodb 
          return $http.get('/userDetails/display/:id', id);
//here is the problem i dont know how to pass id with angular to express(api is working perfectly)/
         },
```

**this is my angular controller**

`user.userDetails(id).success(function(data){
         console.log("data from services to controller", data);
           $scope.userDetails_test = data;
      });`

**this is my angular config file**

```
angular.module('app',  ['todoController', 'todoservice','ui.router']).
  config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
          $stateProvider.state('userDetails', {
            url: '/userDetails/:id',
                controller:'maincontroller',
                 params: {id: null,}
      }); 
  }]);
```

**this is my view**

```
//todo._id==> working perfectly with getting an id in the table with ng-repeat

<a ui-sref="userDetails({id: todo._id})" ng-href = "userDetails/:todo._id" ng-click = "userDetails_scope()">userDetails</a>
```

Comment: You should concat parameter in the URL like `$http.get('/userDetails/display/'+ id);`

Comment: where are you going to pass `id` to?  the `userDetail` state?  or toserver side for fetching data?

Comment: server side fetching data ,

Comment: @pankajparkar, your statement is working perfectly but i need to get my id from the config  to service dynamically by ng-click

Comment: pass the id though the `ng-click` function or even pass the whole object to controller and get the id in controller from the object

Comment: Here every thing ok with the above statement i am getting my id in stateparams while click in it. That store in the $stateparams.id{//temporaray clicking id is stored }---> it reseted while clicking the double click event to my button @charlietfl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to pass the id into ng-click like below -

```
<a id ={id: todo._id} ui-sref="userDetails({id: todo._id})" ng-href = "userDetails/:todo._id" ng-click = "userDetails_scope(todo._id)">userDetails</a>
```

Comment: Id is not passing in the services i need to pass it in backend services

Answer (score 0):

since you are trying to fetching data from server with a `id` patameter, you can use `$http.post`, see documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

sample code:

```
$http.post('/userDetails/display', {id: id})
     .then(function(response) {        // <------mention: here we are using then(success has been deprecated)
       // deal with response result from server here
     })
```

Comment: @pengyy i am using angular 1.2.x without success services i dont know what to use it tried with post method it does in t work for me

Comment: @muthukumar success can be used in 1.2.x, just replace `then` to success

Comment: the problem is within the services the id is passed in the stateprovider but i need to pass it in the services with backend api